# How do I find the reference that is causing NETSDK1136

Tags: .net-core

I want my project to only use Target Framework net5.0

However when I build I get an error

> Error NETSDK1136  The target platform must be set to Windows (usually
> by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using
> Windows Forms or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do
> so.   JT.Module   C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets

I have searched through the project and see no forms or controls.
I don't think there are any in the referenced libraries

How do I find what the reference is?
I notice the error mentions sdk 6.0.102
Where could that be coming from?
The top line of the project is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

SDK does not occur elsewhere in the project.

I am running VS2022 17.1.0

[Update]

I noticed a message

> This project is targeting a version of .NET which is not installed.

So I clicked install and exited VS

[image: message]

However the problem is not fixed.

I notice the following in control panel Programs and Features.
[image: SDKs]

I removed the version 6 SDKs

I decided to create a new clean project and move code from the old to the new.

I notice the old project shows an Imports folder which is not present in the new.

I don't know how to remove it.

[image: imports]

[Update]

I discovered that I was calling MessageBox.Show()

So searching for this helps.
Also searching for system.windows.forms

Comment: What is the `<Project Sdk="...">` value set to in the csproj?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pragmatic answer is to search for Windows.System.Forms

Answer (score 0):

In `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets` file, replace

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

with

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

see [this detailed info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/migration/?view=netdesktop-5.0#project-file).